# How to use ftrScanAPI.dll in Delphi

Tags: delphi, dll

I'm having problem on how to correctly use ftrScanAPI.dll. I got no errors when calling the function "ftrScanOpenDevice" inside the DLL but I get errors "access violation" when calling the procedure "ftrScanCloseDevice". I'm stuck and don't know if I'm on the right track. Am I doing it correctly?

```
TProcedure = procedure; stdcall;
TProcedure_int = procedure(A_Int : Integer); stdcall;


  TFutronicFingerPrint = class
    fHandle : THandle;
    public
      constructor Create;
      destructor Destroy; override;
      procedure Open;
      procedure Close;
  end;

constructor TFutronicFingerPrint.Create;
begin
    inherited;
    fHandle := LoadLibrary('ftrScanAPI.dll');
end;

destructor TFutronicFingerPrint.Destroy;
begin
  FreeLibrary(fHandle);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TFutronicFingerPrint.Open;
var
  procOpenDevice : TProcedure;
begin

    @procOpenDevice := GetProcAddress(fHandle, 'ftrScanOpenDevice');
    if @procOpenDevice <> nil then
    begin
       procOpenDevice;
    end;
end;

procedure TFutronicFingerPrint.Close;
var
  proc : TProcedure_int;
begin

    @proc := GetProcAddress(fHandle, 'ftrScanCloseDevice');
    if @proc <> nil then
    begin
       proc(fHandle);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Do you expect us to Google to track down the DLL, research its documentation to find the declarations of the functions, and then write a Pascal wrapper so we can test your code to see why it doesn't work?

Comment: I'll use my psychic debugging skills, though: I'd be willing to bet that the call to `ftpScanOpenDevice` is actually a function that returns an integer handle for the device you just opened, and that you're supposed to pass that handle into the `ftrScanCloseDevice` call. It makes no sense whatsoever to pass the DLL handle into the procedure.

Comment: @KenWhite: that is **exactly** what it does. `ftrScanOpenDevice()` returns a `FTRHANDLE` as output, which `ftrScanCloseDevice()` then takes as input.

Comment: @Remy: It was pretty clear that the `ftrScanCloseDevice` wouldn't expect a handle to the DLL it was in when closing. Logically that wouldn't make any sense. I'd expect that returned `FTRHANDLE` would be needed when calling all of the other functions that interact with the DLL as well.

Comment: @KenWhite: most of them, yes.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are declaring and using the DLL functions wrong.

`ftpScanOpenevice()` is not a procedure, it is a function that returns an `FTRHANDLE` as output.

`ftrScanCloseDevice()` then takes that `FTRHANDLE` as input, **NOT** the `THandle` that points at the loaded DLL itself.

Try this instead:

```
type
  FTRHANDLE = Pointer;
  ftrScanOpenDeviceFunc = function: FTRHANDLE; stdcall;
  ftrScanCloseDeviceFunc = procedure(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE); stdcall;
  ...

  TFutronicFingerPrint = class
  private
    fHandle : THandle;
    fDevice : FTRHANDLE;
    procOpenDevice : ftrScanOpenDeviceFunc;
    procCloseDevice : ftrScanCloseDeviceFunc;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function Open: Boolean;
    procedure Close;
  end;

constructor TFutronicFingerPrint.Create;
begin
  inherited;

  fHandle := LoadLibrary('ftrScanAPI.dll');
  if fHandle = 0 then RaiseLastOSError;

  @procOpenDevice := GetProcAddress(fHandle, 'ftrScanOpenDevice');
  if not Assigned(procOpenDevice) then RaiseLastOSError;

  @procCloseDevice := GetProcAddress(fHandle, 'ftrScanCloseDevice');
  if not Assigned(procCloseDevice) then RaiseLastOSError;
end;

destructor TFutronicFingerPrint.Destroy;
begin
  Close;
  if fHandle <> 0 then
    FreeLibrary(fHandle);
  inherited;
end;

function TFutronicFingerPrint.Open: Boolean;
begin
  Close;
  fDevice := procOpenDevice();
  Result := fDevice <> nil;
end;

procedure TFutronicFingerPrint.Close;
begin
  if fDevice <> nil then
  begin
    procCloseDevice(fDevice);
    fDevice = nil;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
type
  FTRHANDLE = Pointer;

  TFutronicFingerPrint = class
  private
    fDevice : FTRHANDLE;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function Open: Boolean;
    procedure Close;
  end;

...

function ftrScanOpenDevice: FTRHANDLE; stdcall; external 'ftrScanAPI.dll';
procedure ftrScanCloseDevice(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE); stdcall; external 'ftrScanAPI.dll';
...

constructor TFutronicFingerPrint.Create;
begin
  inherited;
end;

destructor TFutronicFingerPrint.Destroy;
begin
  Close;
  inherited;
end;

function TFutronicFingerPrint.Open: Boolean;
begin
  Close;
  fDevice := ftrScanOpenDevice();
  Result := fDevice <> nil;
end;

procedure TFutronicFingerPrint.Close;
begin
  if fDevice <> nil then
  begin
    ftrScanCloseDevice(fDevice);
    fDevice = nil;
  end;
end;
```

If you get a copy of `ftrScanAPI.h`, it contains the actual C declarations, which can be translated to Delphi, eg:

```
unit ftrScanAPI;

interface

uses
  Windows; 

type
  FTRHANDLE = Pointer; 

const
  FTR_MAX_INTERFACE_NUMBER = 128;

  FTR_OPTIONS_CHECK_FAKE_REPLICA = $00000001;
  FTR_OPTIONS_FAST_FINGER_DETECT_METHOD = $00000002;

  FTR_ERROR_BASE = $20000000;

  FTR_ERROR_EMPTY_FRAME = 4306 { ERROR_EMPTY }; 
  FTR_ERROR_MOVABLE_FINGER = FTR_ERROR_BASE or $0001;
  FTR_ERROR_NO_FRAME = FTR_ERROR_BASE or $0002;
  FTR_ERROR_USER_CANCELED = FTR_ERROR_BASE or $0003;
  FTR_ERROR_HARDWARE_INCOMPATIBLE = FTR_ERROR_BASE or $0004;
  FTR_ERROR_FIRMWARE_INCOMPATIBLE = FTR_ERROR_BASE or $0005;
  FTR_ERROR_INVALID_AUTHORIZATION_CODE = FTR_ERROR_BASE or $0006;

  FTR_CONST_COLOR_SMALL_IMAGE_WIDTH = 256;
  FTR_CONST_COLOR_SMALL_IMAGE_HEIGHT = 150;
  FTR_CONST_COLOR_SMALL_IMAGE_SIZE = FTR_CONST_COLOR_SMALL_IMAGE_WIDTH * FTR_CONST_COLOR_SMALL_IMAGE_HEIGHT;

  FTR_CONST_CALIBRATION_SKIP_IR = $00000001;
  FTR_CONST_CALIBRATION_SKIP_FUZZY = $00000002;

  FTR_CONST_DIODE_OFF: Byte = 0; 
  FTR_CONST_DIODE_ON: Byte = 255; 

  _FTRSCAN_IMAGE_SIZE = packed record
    nWidth: Integer;
    nHeight: Integer;
    nImageSize: Integer;
  end;
  FTRSCAN_IMAGE_SIZE = _FTRSCAN_IMAGE_SIZE;
  PFTRSCAN_IMAGE_SIZE = ^_FTRSCAN_IMAGE_SIZE; 

  _FTRSCAN_FAKE_REPLICA_PARAMETERS = packed record
    bCalculated: BOOL;
    nCalculatedSum1: Integer;
    nCalculatedSumFuzzy: Integer; 
    nCalculatedSumEmpty: Integer;
    nCalculatedSum2: Integer;
    dblCalculatedTremor: Double;
    dblCalculatedValue: Double;
  end;
  FTRSCAN_FAKE_REPLICA_PARAMETERS = _FTRSCAN_FAKE_REPLICA_PARAMETERS;
  PFTRSCAN_FAKE_REPLICA_PARAMETERS = ^_FTRSCAN_FAKE_REPLICA_PARAMETERS;

  _FTRSCAN_FRAME_PARAMETERS = packed record
    nContrastOnDose2: Integer;
    nContrastOnDose4: Integer; 
    nDose: Integer;
    nBrightnessOnDose1: Integer;
    nBrightnessOnDose2: Integer;
    nBrightnessOnDose3: Integer;
    nBrightnessOnDose4: Integer;
    FakeReplicaParams: FTRSCAN_FAKE_REPLICA_PARAMETERS;
    Reserved: array[0..64-SizeOf(FTRSCAN_FAKE_REPLICA_PARAMETERS)-1] of Byte;
  end;
  FTRSCAN_FRAME_PARAMETERS = _FTRSCAN_FRAME_PARAMETERS;
  PFTRSCAN_FRAME_PARAMETERS = ^_FTRSCAN_FRAME_PARAMETERS;

  __FTRSCAN_INTERFACE_STATUS = (
    FTRSCAN_INTERFACE_STATUS_CONNECTED, 
    FTRSCAN_INTERFACE_STATUS_DISCONNECTED 
  );
  FTRSCAN_INTERFACE_STATUS = __FTRSCAN_INTERFACE_STATUS;
  PFTRSCAN_INTERFACE_STATUS = ^__FTRSCAN_INTERFACE_STATUS;

  __FTRSCAN_INTERFACES_LIST = packed record
    InterfaceStatus: array[0..FTR_MAX_INTERFACE_NUMBER-1] of FTRSCAN_INTERFACE_STATUS;
  end;
  FTRSCAN_INTERFACES_LIST = __FTRSCAN_INTERFACES_LIST;
  PFTRSCAN_INTERFACES_LIST = ^__FTRSCAN_INTERFACES_LIST;

function ftrScanOpenDevice: FTRHANDLE; stdcall; 
function ftrScanOpenDeviceOnInterface(nInterface: Integer): FTRHANDLE; stdcall;
procedure ftrScanCloseDevice(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE); stdcall; 
function ftrScanSetOptions(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; dwMask, dwFlags: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall; 
function ftrScanGetOptions(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; lpdwFlags: LPDWORD): BOOL; stdcall;

function ftrScanGetInterfaces(pInterfaceList: PFTRSCAN_INTERFACES_LIST): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrSetBaseInterface(nBaseInterface: Integer): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrGetBaseInterfaceNumber: Integer; stdcall;

function ftrScanGetFakeReplicaInterval(pdblMinFakeReplicaValue, pdblMaxFakeReplicaValue: PDouble): BOOL; stdcall;
procedure ftrScanSetFakeReplicaInterval(dblMinFakeReplicaValue, dblMaxFakeReplicaValue: Double); stdcall;

function ftrScanGetImageSize(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pImageSize: PFTRSCAN_IMAGE_SIZE): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrScanGetImage(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; nDose: Integer; pBuffer: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrScanGetFuzzyImage(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pBuffer: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrScanGetBacklightImage(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pBuffer: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrScanGetDarkImage(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pBuffer: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrScanGetColourImage(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pDoubleSizeBuffer: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrScanGetSmallColourImage(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pSmallBuffer: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrScanGetColorDarkImage(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pDoubleSizeBuffer: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall;

function ftrScanIsFingerPresent(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pFrameParameters: PFTRSCAN_FRAME_PARAMETERS): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrScanGetFrame(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pBuffer: Pointer; pFrameParameters: PFTRSCAN_FRAME_PARAMETERS): BOOL; stdcall;

function ftrScanSave7Bytes(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pBuffer: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrScanRestore7Bytes(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pBuffer: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall;

type
  PFTRCALIBRATEFNCB = function(pContext, pParams: Pointer): BOOL; cdecl;

function ftrScanZeroCalibration(pfnCallbackProc: PFTRCALIBRATEFNCB; pContext: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall; 
function ftrScanZeroCalibration2(dwOptions: DWORD; pfnCallbackProc: PFTRCALIBRATEFNCB; pContext: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrScanGetCalibrationConstants(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pbyIRConst, pbyFuzzyConst: PByte): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrScanStoreCalibrationConstants(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; byIRConst, byFuzzyConst: Byte; bBurnInFlash: BOOL): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrScanGetFakeReplicaParameters(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pFakeReplicaParams: PFTRSCAN_FAKE_REPLICA_PARAMETERS): BOOL; stdcall;

function ftrScanSetNewAuthorizationCode(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pSevenBytesAuthorizationCode: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrScanSaveSecret7Bytes(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pSevenBytesAuthorizationCode, pBuffer: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrScanRestoreSecret7Bytes(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pSevenBytesAuthorizationCode, pBuffer: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall; 

function ftrScanSetDiodesStatus(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; byGreenDiodeStatus, byRedDiodeStatus: Byte): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrScanGetDiodesStatus(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pbIsGreenDiodeOn, pbIsRedDiodeOn: PBOOL): BOOL; stdcall;

implementation

const
  ftrScanAPI = 'ftrScanAPI.dll';

function ftrScanOpenDevice; external ftrScanAPI;

function ftrScanOpenDeviceOnInterface; external ftrScanAPI;
procedure ftrScanCloseDevice; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanSetOptions; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanGetOptions; external ftrScanAPI;

function ftrScanGetInterfaces; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrSetBaseInterface; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrGetBaseInterfaceNumber; external ftrScanAPI;

function ftrScanGetFakeReplicaInterval; external ftrScanAPI;
procedure ftrScanSetFakeReplicaInterval; external ftrScanAPI;

function ftrScanGetImageSize; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanGetImage; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanGetFuzzyImage; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanGetBacklightImage; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanGetDarkImage; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanGetColourImage; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanGetSmallColourImage; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanGetColorDarkImage; external ftrScanAPI;

function ftrScanIsFingerPresent; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanGetFrame; external ftrScanAPI;

function ftrScanSave7Bytes; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanRestore7Bytes; external ftrScanAPI;

function ftrScanZeroCalibration; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanZeroCalibration2; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanGetCalibrationConstants; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanStoreCalibrationConstants; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanGetFakeReplicaParameters; external ftrScanAPI;

function ftrScanSetNewAuthorizationCode; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanSaveSecret7Bytes; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanRestoreSecret7Bytes; external ftrScanAPI;

function ftrScanSetDiodesStatus; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanGetDiodesStatus; external ftrScanAPI;

end.
```

```
uses
  ..., ftrScanAPI;

  TFutronicFingerPrint = class
  private
    fDevice : FTRHANDLE;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function Open: Boolean;
    procedure Close;
  end;

...

constructor TFutronicFingerPrint.Create;
begin
  inherited;
end;

destructor TFutronicFingerPrint.Destroy;
begin
  Close;
  inherited;
end;

function TFutronicFingerPrint.Open: Boolean;
begin
  Close;
  fDevice := ftrScanOpenDevice();
  Result := fDevice <> nil;
end;

procedure TFutronicFingerPrint.Close;
begin
  if fDevice <> nil then
  begin
    ftrScanCloseDevice(fDevice);
    fDevice = nil;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You beat me to it (and did much better than I did). :-)

Comment: thank you so much.. I'll update things once I've tested

Comment: @KenWhite - ah, but your Jedi Mind-Debugging skills were most impressive all the same.

Comment: An error is occurring in the ERROR_EMPTY statement.
Where should this statement appear?

Comment: @MenandroNeto `ERROR_EMPTY` is a Win32 error code. If your `Windows` unit does not declare it, then the value has to be declared manually. I have updated the declaration based on [this version](https://github.com/erikssm/futronics-fingerprint-reader/blob/master/ftrScanAPI.h) of `ftrScanAPI.h`

Comment: Thank you so much... I'll update things once I've tested.

Answer (score 0):

Follow changes:

```
unit UftrScanAPI;

interface

uses
  Windows;

type
  FTRHANDLE = Pointer;

const
  FTR_MAX_INTERFACE_NUMBER = 128;

  FTR_OPTIONS_CHECK_FAKE_REPLICA = $00000001;
  FTR_OPTIONS_FAST_FINGER_DETECT_METHOD = $00000002;

  FTR_ERROR_BASE = $20000000;
  ERROR_EMPTY = FTR_ERROR_BASE;
  FTR_ERROR_EMPTY_FRAME = ERROR_EMPTY;
  FTR_ERROR_MOVABLE_FINGER = FTR_ERROR_BASE or $0001;
  FTR_ERROR_NO_FRAME = FTR_ERROR_BASE or $0002;
  FTR_ERROR_USER_CANCELED = FTR_ERROR_BASE or $0003;
  FTR_ERROR_HARDWARE_INCOMPATIBLE = FTR_ERROR_BASE or $0004;
  FTR_ERROR_FIRMWARE_INCOMPATIBLE = FTR_ERROR_BASE or $0005;
  FTR_ERROR_INVALID_AUTHORIZATION_CODE = FTR_ERROR_BASE or $0006;

  FTR_CONST_COLOR_SMALL_IMAGE_WIDTH = 256;
  FTR_CONST_COLOR_SMALL_IMAGE_HEIGHT = 150;
  FTR_CONST_COLOR_SMALL_IMAGE_SIZE = FTR_CONST_COLOR_SMALL_IMAGE_WIDTH * FTR_CONST_COLOR_SMALL_IMAGE_HEIGHT;

  FTR_CONST_CALIBRATION_SKIP_IR = $00000001;
  FTR_CONST_CALIBRATION_SKIP_FUZZY = $00000002;

  FTR_CONST_DIODE_OFF: Byte = 0;
  FTR_CONST_DIODE_ON: Byte = 255;

type
  _FTRSCAN_IMAGE_SIZE = packed record
    nWidth: Integer;
    nHeight: Integer;
    nImageSize: Integer;
  end;
  FTRSCAN_IMAGE_SIZE = _FTRSCAN_IMAGE_SIZE;
  PFTRSCAN_IMAGE_SIZE = ^_FTRSCAN_IMAGE_SIZE;

  _FTRSCAN_FAKE_REPLICA_PARAMETERS = packed record
    bCalculated: BOOL;
    nCalculatedSum1: Integer;
    nCalculatedSumFuzzy: Integer; 
    nCalculatedSumEmpty: Integer;
    nCalculatedSum2: Integer;
    dblCalculatedTremor: Double;
    dblCalculatedValue: Double;
  end;
  FTRSCAN_FAKE_REPLICA_PARAMETERS = _FTRSCAN_FAKE_REPLICA_PARAMETERS;
  PFTRSCAN_FAKE_REPLICA_PARAMETERS = ^_FTRSCAN_FAKE_REPLICA_PARAMETERS;

  _FTRSCAN_FRAME_PARAMETERS = packed record
    nContrastOnDose2: Integer;
    nContrastOnDose4: Integer;
    nDose: Integer;
    nBrightnessOnDose1: Integer;
    nBrightnessOnDose2: Integer;
    nBrightnessOnDose3: Integer;
    nBrightnessOnDose4: Integer;
    FakeReplicaParams: FTRSCAN_FAKE_REPLICA_PARAMETERS;
    Reserved: array[0..64-SizeOf(FTRSCAN_FAKE_REPLICA_PARAMETERS)-1] of Byte;
  end;
  FTRSCAN_FRAME_PARAMETERS = _FTRSCAN_FRAME_PARAMETERS;
  PFTRSCAN_FRAME_PARAMETERS = ^_FTRSCAN_FRAME_PARAMETERS;

  __FTRSCAN_INTERFACE_STATUS = (
    FTRSCAN_INTERFACE_STATUS_CONNECTED, 
    FTRSCAN_INTERFACE_STATUS_DISCONNECTED 
  );
  FTRSCAN_INTERFACE_STATUS = __FTRSCAN_INTERFACE_STATUS;
  PFTRSCAN_INTERFACE_STATUS = ^__FTRSCAN_INTERFACE_STATUS;

  __FTRSCAN_INTERFACES_LIST = packed record
    InterfaceStatus: array[0..FTR_MAX_INTERFACE_NUMBER-1] of FTRSCAN_INTERFACE_STATUS;
  end;
  FTRSCAN_INTERFACES_LIST = __FTRSCAN_INTERFACES_LIST;
  PFTRSCAN_INTERFACES_LIST = ^__FTRSCAN_INTERFACES_LIST;

function ftrScanOpenDevice: FTRHANDLE; stdcall; 
function ftrScanOpenDeviceOnInterface(nInterface: Integer): FTRHANDLE; stdcall;
procedure ftrScanCloseDevice(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE); stdcall; 
function ftrScanSetOptions(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; dwMask, dwFlags: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall; 
function ftrScanGetOptions(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; lpdwFlags: LPDWORD): BOOL; stdcall;

function ftrScanGetInterfaces(pInterfaceList: PFTRSCAN_INTERFACES_LIST): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrSetBaseInterface(nBaseInterface: Integer): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrGetBaseInterfaceNumber: Integer; stdcall;

function ftrScanGetFakeReplicaInterval(pdblMinFakeReplicaValue, pdblMaxFakeReplicaValue: PDouble): BOOL; stdcall;
procedure ftrScanSetFakeReplicaInterval(dblMinFakeReplicaValue, dblMaxFakeReplicaValue: Double); stdcall;

function ftrScanGetImageSize(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pImageSize: PFTRSCAN_IMAGE_SIZE): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrScanGetImage(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; nDose: Integer; pBuffer: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrScanGetFuzzyImage(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pBuffer: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrScanGetBacklightImage(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pBuffer: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrScanGetDarkImage(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pBuffer: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrScanGetColourImage(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pDoubleSizeBuffer: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrScanGetSmallColourImage(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pSmallBuffer: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrScanGetColorDarkImage(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pDoubleSizeBuffer: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall;

function ftrScanIsFingerPresent(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pFrameParameters: PFTRSCAN_FRAME_PARAMETERS): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrScanGetFrame(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pBuffer: Pointer; pFrameParameters: PFTRSCAN_FRAME_PARAMETERS): BOOL; stdcall;

function ftrScanSave7Bytes(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pBuffer: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrScanRestore7Bytes(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pBuffer: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall;

type
  PFTRCALIBRATEFNCB = function(pContext, pParams: Pointer): BOOL; cdecl;

function ftrScanZeroCalibration(pfnCallbackProc: PFTRCALIBRATEFNCB; pContext: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall; 
function ftrScanZeroCalibration2(dwOptions: DWORD; pfnCallbackProc: PFTRCALIBRATEFNCB; pContext: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrScanGetCalibrationConstants(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pbyIRConst, pbyFuzzyConst: PByte): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrScanStoreCalibrationConstants(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; byIRConst, byFuzzyConst: Byte; bBurnInFlash: BOOL): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrScanGetFakeReplicaParameters(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pFakeReplicaParams: PFTRSCAN_FAKE_REPLICA_PARAMETERS): BOOL; stdcall;

function ftrScanSetNewAuthorizationCode(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pSevenBytesAuthorizationCode: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrScanSaveSecret7Bytes(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pSevenBytesAuthorizationCode, pBuffer: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrScanRestoreSecret7Bytes(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pSevenBytesAuthorizationCode, pBuffer: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall; 

function ftrScanSetDiodesStatus(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; byGreenDiodeStatus, byRedDiodeStatus: Byte): BOOL; stdcall;
function ftrScanGetDiodesStatus(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pbIsGreenDiodeOn, pbIsRedDiodeOn: PBOOL): BOOL; stdcall;

implementation

const
  ftrScanAPI = 'ftrScanAPI.dll';

function ftrScanOpenDevice; external ftrScanAPI;

function ftrScanOpenDeviceOnInterface; external ftrScanAPI;
procedure ftrScanCloseDevice; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanSetOptions; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanGetOptions; external ftrScanAPI;

function ftrScanGetInterfaces; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrSetBaseInterface; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrGetBaseInterfaceNumber; external ftrScanAPI;

function ftrScanGetFakeReplicaInterval; external ftrScanAPI;
procedure ftrScanSetFakeReplicaInterval; external ftrScanAPI;

function ftrScanGetImageSize; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanGetImage; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanGetFuzzyImage; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanGetBacklightImage; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanGetDarkImage; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanGetColourImage; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanGetSmallColourImage; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanGetColorDarkImage; external ftrScanAPI;

function ftrScanIsFingerPresent; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanGetFrame; external ftrScanAPI;

function ftrScanSave7Bytes; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanRestore7Bytes; external ftrScanAPI;

function ftrScanZeroCalibration; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanZeroCalibration2; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanGetCalibrationConstants; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanStoreCalibrationConstants; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanGetFakeReplicaParameters; external ftrScanAPI;

function ftrScanSetNewAuthorizationCode; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanSaveSecret7Bytes; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanRestoreSecret7Bytes; external ftrScanAPI;

function ftrScanSetDiodesStatus; external ftrScanAPI;
function ftrScanGetDiodesStatus; external ftrScanAPI;

end.
```

Comment: Was it really necessary to post this answer containing the same code I posted 3 years ago? All you did was change the unit name and add the `ERROR_EMPTY` declaration, which isn't even using the correct value. If you had an issue with my code, you could have just commented that.

Comment: Did you forget to say, what is the value of the constant ERROR_EMPTY?

Comment: no. That was addressed in an update to the code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still working on the code. Implemented dynamic load of dll:

```
unit UClinicAllFtrScanAPI;

interface

uses
  Classes, Windows, SysUtils;

type
  // API Futronic
  FTRHANDLE = Pointer;

  _FTRSCAN_FAKE_REPLICA_PARAMETERS = packed record
    bCalculated: BOOL;
    nCalculatedSum1: Integer;
    nCalculatedSumFuzzy: Integer;
    nCalculatedSumEmpty: Integer;
    nCalculatedSum2: Integer;
    dblCalculatedTremor: Double;
    dblCalculatedValue: Double;
  end;
  FTRSCAN_FAKE_REPLICA_PARAMETERS = _FTRSCAN_FAKE_REPLICA_PARAMETERS;
  PFTRSCAN_FAKE_REPLICA_PARAMETERS = ^_FTRSCAN_FAKE_REPLICA_PARAMETERS;

  _FTRSCAN_FRAME_PARAMETERS = packed record
    nContrastOnDose2: Integer;
    nContrastOnDose4: Integer;
    nDose: Integer;
    nBrightnessOnDose1: Integer;
    nBrightnessOnDose2: Integer;
    nBrightnessOnDose3: Integer;
    nBrightnessOnDose4: Integer;
    FakeReplicaParams: FTRSCAN_FAKE_REPLICA_PARAMETERS;
    Reserved: array[0..64-SizeOf(FTRSCAN_FAKE_REPLICA_PARAMETERS)-1] of Byte;
  end;
  FTRSCAN_FRAME_PARAMETERS = _FTRSCAN_FRAME_PARAMETERS;
  PFTRSCAN_FRAME_PARAMETERS = ^_FTRSCAN_FRAME_PARAMETERS;

  _FTRSCAN_IMAGE_SIZE = packed record
    nWidth: Integer;
    nHeight: Integer;
    nImageSize: Integer;
  end;
  FTRSCAN_IMAGE_SIZE = _FTRSCAN_IMAGE_SIZE;
  PFTRSCAN_IMAGE_SIZE = ^_FTRSCAN_IMAGE_SIZE;

  // Methods from dll

  TFutronicSDKIsFingerPresent = function (ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pFrameParameters: PFTRSCAN_FRAME_PARAMETERS): BOOL; stdcall;
  TFutronicSDKOpenDevice = function: FTRHANDLE; stdcall;
  TFutronicSDKCloseDevice = procedure (ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE); stdcall;
  TFutronicSDKSetDiodesStatus = function (ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; byGreenDiodeStatus, byRedDiodeStatus: Byte): BOOL; stdcall;
  TFutronicSDKGetDiodesStatus = function(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pbIsGreenDiodeOn, pbIsRedDiodeOn: PBOOL): BOOL; stdcall;
  TFutronicSDKGetImageSize = function(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; pImageSize: PFTRSCAN_IMAGE_SIZE): BOOL; stdcall;
  TFutronicSDKGetImage = function(ftrHandle: FTRHANDLE; nDose: Integer; pBuffer: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall;

  TClinicAllFutronicScanAPI = class(TComponent)
  private
    FDLLHandle: THandle;              // dll Handle
    FDevice: FTRHANDLE;

    FConnected: boolean;
    FLastReturn: integer;

    FIsFingerPresent: TFutronicSDKIsFingerPresent;
    FOpenDevice: TFutronicSDKOpenDevice;
    FCloseDevice: TFutronicSDKCloseDevice;
    FSetDiodesStatus: TFutronicSDKSetDiodesStatus;
    FGetDiodesStatus: TFutronicSDKGetDiodesStatus;
    FGetImageSize: TFutronicSDKGetImageSize;
    FGetImage: TFutronicSDKGetImage;

    function GetConnected: boolean;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); reintroduce;
    destructor Destroy; reintroduce;
    procedure Free; overload;

    function Open: Boolean;
    procedure Close;
  published
    property Connected: boolean read GetConnected default false;
    property LastReturn: integer read FLastReturn default -1;
  end;

implementation

const
  DLL_FtrScanAPI = 'ftrScanAPI.dll';

{ TClinicAllFutronicScanAPI }

constructor TClinicAllFutronicScanAPI.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  FDLLHandle := LoadLibrary(DLL_FtrScanAPI);
  if FDLLHandle <> 0 then
  begin
    @FIsFingerPresent   := GetProcAddress(FDLLHandle, 'ftrScanIsFingerPresent');
    @FOpenDevice        := GetProcAddress(FDLLHandle, 'ftrScanOpenDevice');
    @FCloseDevice       := GetProcAddress(FDLLHandle, 'ftrScanCloseDevice');
    @FSetDiodesStatus   := GetProcAddress(FDLLHandle, 'ftrScanSetDiodesStatus');
    @FGetDiodesStatus   := GetProcAddress(FDLLHandle, 'ftrScanGetDiodesStatus');
    @FGetImageSize      := GetProcAddress(FDLLHandle, 'ftrScanGetImageSize');
    @FGetImage          := GetProcAddress(FDLLHandle, 'ftrScanGetImage');
  end
  else
    raise Exception.CreateFmt('Biblioteca dinâmica não encontrada %s!', [DLL_FtrScanAPI]);

  inherited Create(AOwner);
end;

destructor TClinicAllFutronicScanAPI.Destroy;
begin
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TClinicAllFutronicScanAPI.Free;
begin
  if Assigned(self.FDevice) then
    self.FCloseDevice(self.FDevice);

  FreeLibrary(FDLLHandle);

  inherited Free;
end;

function TClinicAllFutronicScanAPI.GetConnected: boolean;
begin
  result := FConnected;
end;

function TClinicAllFutronicScanAPI.Open: Boolean;
begin
  Close;
  fDevice := self.FOpenDevice;
  FConnected := fDevice <> nil;
  Result := FConnected;
end;

procedure TClinicAllFutronicScanAPI.Close;
begin
  if fDevice <> nil then
  begin
    FCloseDevice(fDevice);
    fDevice := nil;
  end;
end;

end.
```